# how to calculate rlnorm for each row? x<-rlnorm(n,GM, GSD) take n=200. i want 3rd row as normal log distribution

Tags: r

how to calculate rlnorm for each row? `x<-rlnorm(n,GM, GSD)` take `n=200`. I want 3rd row as normal log distribution.

```
                   1        2         3         4         5        6        7
Sheet1.GM  0.6931472 1.098612 0.6931472 0.6931472 0.6931472 1.098612 1.386294
Sheet1.GSD 1.6094379 1.945910 1.7917595 1.3862944 0.6931472 2.197225 1.609438
```

Comment: Do you want to do `rlnorm(200, GM, GSD)` where GM takes the values of the first row and GSD values of the second one?

Comment: apply(rlnorm,1,x)